# Git reset restores ignored file?

Tags: git

My `wp-config.php` was under git and now I want to ignore it.

I've added it to `.gitignore`, commited the new `.gitignore` and 
then executed
`git update-index --assume-unchanged -- wp-config.php`

Now, when I execute `git reset --hard` the `wp-config.php` file is restored back though I want it to ignore it...it is still being re-fetched from git. Any ideas why?

Comment: You should remove a file if you want it to be not touched by git.

Comment: remove a file as in `git rm` ?

Answer (score 1):

`.gitignore` only works for untracked files. As soon as a file is tracked (added to the index) `.gitignore` has not effect whatsoever. If you want `.gitignore` to be in effect, you need to delete the file from the repository.

`--assume-unchanged` is a very dangerous option, especially if you don't know what it means. You are not telling Git to not touch the file, but you tell it that this file is unchanged, no matter what it finds in its contents. This means, that if you switch branches or if you use reset or similar things, Git assumes the file is unchanged and happily overwrites any local changes you have done to the file where it normally would warn you and refuse to overwrite changes that would be lost otherwise.

There is **no** safe way to tell Git to ignore changes to an already tracked file, becuase that is against the sense of tracking a file. Instead the pattern is to have the file checked in as `wp-config.php.sample` or `wp-config.php.template` or similar and have `wp-config.php` in `.gitignore`.

Another acceptable way if you can control the consumer of `wp-config.php` is to make it look for a second file `wp-config-local.php` or similar and add that to `.gitignore`. If it is not present it will be ignored, if it is present it will overwrite the stuff from the checked-in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: so, there is no way of 'un-gitting' a file which was already checked into git except referencing another file (include/require) ? that's odd.

Comment: Ungitting is removing the file from the repository. `git rm file` or `git rm --cached file` to only remove it from the repository but keeping the worktree file. (but only for you, everyone else will get the delete when they update and need to restore the file manually after that) Making git ignoring changes to a tracked file is not possible, no. This is not odd, but by design. If a file is tracked, you want to track the changes to it, that is the sense of tracking a file.

Comment: Fortunately `--assume-unchanged` doesn't actually have Git overwrite the file, in tests I have made, but I'm not sure if this is true of *all* Git versions. Do you know of situations where it *does* assume the file is unchanged and actually overwrite it?

Comment: It is not a matter of Git version, but a matter of your test case. Have two branches where the file differs. Checkout one, modify the file, do the --assume-unchanged, then checkout the other one and you will see the file gets overwritten silently. If you don't do Git actions that need to modify the file like switching between branches where the file is identical or resetting to a state where the file is identical, there is no need to overwrite the file.